# ruby passing value into array using send

Tags: ruby

I am new to ruby , can someone explain what the second and 3rd line do?

```
a = [6,7,8]
a.send :[]=,0,2
a[0] + a.[](1) + a.send(:[],2)
```

First line is assigning an array to the variable a.

I am totally lost on second and third line. hope someone can give some detail explannations.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`.send`  invokes the method identified by symbol, passing it any arguments specified.

```
a.send :[]=,0,2
```

is same as

```
a.send(:[]=, 0, 2)
```

Means invoke [[]=](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D) method on the array object with first parameter as `0` and second parameter as `2`.

So this is `a[0] = 2`, set the first element of the array to `2`.

After executed `a.send :[]=,0,2`, `a` becomes `[2, 7, 8]`.

`a.[](1)` is same as `a[1]`

`a.send(:[], 2)` is same as `a.[](2)` which is `a[2]`.

So `a[0] + a.[](1) + a.send(:[],2)` equals `a[0] + a[1] + a[2]` equals `2 +7 + 8` equals `17`.

Comment: in assignment, we use two arguments viz ```a.[]=(0,2)``` and ```a.send :[], 0, 2``` are equivalent. by symmetry, one would expect that for accessing elements  ```a.send :[], 2``` can also be written ```a.[]=(2)```. but instead ```[]=``` operator only takes one argument. i wonder why the designers of the language chose not to preserve the symmetry here.

Answer (score 3):

```
a.send :[]=,0,2 ###same as a[0] = 2

a.[](1) ### same as a[1]

a.send(:[],2) ## same as  a[1]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try the code in irb and see what happens. `send` means sending the following messages to an object. This feature is inherited from Smalltalk.

So `a.send :[]=,0,2` means send the parameter `:[]=,0,2` to a. The parenthesis is omitted. The first parameter `:[]=` is the method to be called by `a`. Starting with a `:` means it is a symbol. `[]=` is the method name. The other parameters of send are treated as the parameter of `[]=`.

As you can see in line 3,   `a.[](1)` is equivalent to `a[1]` in any C-like languages. And `a.[]= 0,2` is `a[0]=2`.